# Why is the RH850G3K processor missing in my IDA?

Tags: ida

Why there aren't RH850 series(like RH850G3K) processors in the processor type list in my IDA? (IDA website says they are supported)

I use IDA Pro 7.0

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so after looking into this a bit further I came to the following conclusion. This *may* work for you by picking another processor model supported by the `nec850` processor module. However, **RH850 support in particular was only introduced in IDA 7.2.**

---

Looking further we can see in the Wikipedia article on [Renesas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renesas_Electronics) we find out why it ended up in the `nec850` processor module:

> #### History
>
> **Renesas Electronics started operation in April 2010, through
>   the integration of NEC Electronics Corporation and Renesas Technology
>   Corporation.** NEC Electronics was established in November 2002 by a
>   spin-off of the semiconductor operations of NEC. Renesas Technology
>   was established on April 1, 2003, as a joint venture of Hitachi, Ltd.
>   (55%) and Mitsubishi Electric (45%).

The name RH850 is actually not used in the IDA SDK 7.0 and 7.1 (this particular processor module comes with source code included as also indicated on the Hex-Rays website).

And in the [release information for IDA 7.2](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/7.2/index.shtml) we can read:

> The NEC 850 processor module has been extended to handle new
>   addressing modes and instructions for V850E2M and RH850 from Renesas.

So no support prior to IDA 7.2 as I already surmised. In the IDA SDK 7.2 we can then find this:

```
static const char *const shnames[] =
{
  "V850",
  "V850E",
  "V850E1",
  "V850E2M",
  "RH850",
  NULL
};

static const char *const lnames[] =
{
  FAMILY"NEC V850",
  "NEC V850E",
  "NEC/Renesas V850E1/ES",
  "NEC/Renesas V850E2/E2M",
  "Renesas RH850",
  NULL
};
```

(This should also provide the clue which possible alternative names you could try for rudimentary support using related processor models. *All* of those are implemented in that same `nec850` processor module.)